# CronJobs not working on video script

Tags: cron, ffmpeg

I've basically installed ffmpeg on a vps with 20.04 ubuntu

I am trying to create a video in /home/ubuntu/video folder - so i am asking script to select all jpeg files in that folder

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -qscale 3 -s 1920x1080 -c:v wmv1 video.wmv
```

which works perfectly and creates a video

so i have now asked cronjobs to do this automatically - every 2 minuted therefore created an sh file and used this script

```
*/2 * * * * /home/ubuntu/video/makewmv.sh
```

and this is the .sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -qscale 3 -s 1920x1080 -c:v wmv1 video.wmv
```

and when i do grep CRON logs i get this

```
Dec 29 23:16:01 vps-1fd6f1ab CRON[16186]: (ubuntu) CMD (/home/ubuntu/video/makewmv.sh)
```

But i do not have the video.wmv ..

I can see the cronjobs are doing what it suppose to be doing - however i am doing something wrong

Can someone help please

I really appreciate it.

(I am extremely new to Linux)

Comment: Have you tried logging and examining the job's output/errors ex. `/home/ubuntu/video/makewmv.sh >/home/ubuntu/cron.log 2>&1` ?

Comment: Thank you for your response - i am getting  Could not open file : *.jpg and 'Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options'

Comment: ... you probably need to add a `cd /home/ubuntu/video/` before the `ffmpeg` command in your script

Comment: Still having issues  - i changed the crontab -e to `*/2 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/video/ ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -qscale 3 -s 1920x1080 -c:v wmv1 video.wmv` still not winining!!

Comment: I'd suggest you ad the `cd` command inside the **script**, however if you wish to add it as part of the cron job it needs to be a separate command separated from the `ffmpeg` command by either `&&` or `;`

Comment: Thank you for your help! Still getting same issue and i am about to give it up :S happy new year by the way

Answer (score 0):

```
*/2 * * * * /home/ubuntu/video/makewmv.sh
```

Put this in your cron file, and then `cd` to the correct directory in your bash script, which should be as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/ubuntu/video
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -qscale 3 -s 1920x1080 -c:v wmv1 video.wmv > makewmv.log 2>&1
```